# Getting Customer Collection

Tags: attributes, collection

How do I add company and group name to this collection

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')               
               ->addAttributeToSelect('*')             
               ->joinAttribute('billing_street', 'customer_address/street', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('billing_fax', 'customer_address/fax', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('billing_country_code', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left')               

               ->joinAttribute('shipping_street', 'customer_address/street', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('shipping_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('shipping_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('shipping_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('shipping_fax', 'customer_address/fax', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('shipping_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('shipping_country_code', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('taxvat', 'customer/taxvat', 'entity_id', null, 'left');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Company is a customer_address attribute, therefore you have to decide wether it should be from the shipping or billing address or join both like the rest.

And group name, like this:

```
$collection->joinTable('customer/customer_group', 'customer_group_id=group_id', array('customer_group_code'), null, 'left');
```

Didn't tested it ;-)

It is important to set as the condition the column of the joined table as first name.

I wrote a blog article about it: http://blog.fabian-blechschmidt.de/articles/Joining-a-flat-table-on-EAV.html

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.Error is  `Uncaught exception 'Mage_Eav_Exception' with message 'Invalid attribute name: customer_group_id.`

Comment: change the condition to 'customer_group_id=group_id' the first "parameter" must be the name from the joined table. The error is raise because of this: http://blog.fabian-blechschmidt.de/articles/Joining-a-flat-table-on-EAV.html#the_hard_part_check_the_bind

Comment: I made a few corrections to the code above.